# NodeJS: break Array.some loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have the following function that receives a JSON array templates and returns a JSON object.

The code executes the console.log. However, it always returns the null at the end of the function. Any ideas?

```
function getTemplate(templates, myId) {
  Object.keys(templates).some(obj => {
    if (templates[obj].id === myId) {
      console.log('HELLO');
      return templates[obj];
    }
  });
  return null;
}
```

**template array**

```
[
    {
        "id": 80,
        "name": "template 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 81,
        "name": "template 2"
    }
]
```

However, it always returns null.

Comment: `return templates[obj];` would return in the context of the `.some(function)` surely

Comment: `.some` is not the right method to find a specific entry in an array.

Comment: @George: Yea, it returns a truthy value to the `.some` function, which will tell you the right template exists, only to `return null` in the end.

Comment: @Cerbrus so how can I return that value then?

Comment: `var result = templates.find(t => t.id === myId)` ->. `result` will be the found template, or `null` if it's not found.

Comment: @Cerbrus `.find()` is preferred because it halts iteration when the value is found, while `.filter()` does not.

Comment: @Pointy: Updated :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is working example,

use `.find` instead of `.some`. We always expect to get one object.

```js
function getTemplate(templates, myId) {
  return templates.find(template => template.id === myId);
}

var array =
[
    {
        "id": 80,
        "name": "template 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 81,
        "name": "template 2"
    }
]
console.log(getTemplate(array, 80));
```

Comment: That's not how `.filter` works.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks, I've just realized that, we should use `.find` instead. I've updated my answer.